Invalid value software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
We are trying to use AWS serverless MSK for Apache Druid ingestion with IAM authentication. I am getting following error on Druid console even though I added aws-msk-iam-auth jar in Druid/libs folder.
"message": "Invalid value software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler for configuration sasl.client.callback.handler.class: Class software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler could not be found.",
Also tried JAVA classpath using following command on EC2 start up script
export CLASSPATH=/local/druid/apache-druid/lib/aws-msk-iam-auth-2.1.0-all.jar:$CLASSPATH
but none of them working
Also referred this link but not able to figure out how this will work for our set up where our druid folder already contains kafka-client prebuilt jar, I cannot make edit in bundling of that jar.

Issue got resolved post copying aws-msk-iam-auth-2.1.0-all.jar under following subfolders of Druid and rebuilding the new Druid jar

apache-druid-29.0.1/extensions/druid-kafka-indexing-service/
apache-druid-29.0.1/extensions/druid-ranger-security/
apache-druid-29.0.1/extensions/druid-kafka-extraction-namespace/
apache-druid-29.0.1/extensions/kafka-emitter/


One of my colleagues faced the same issue and I asked him to check the dependency required for this class. The error message clearly states that the class IAMClientCallbackHandler is not found. You might need to check whether aws.iam dependency is added to your project.
Thanks
